# Why can a struct contain a pointer to another struct that is not defined?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
int main(void)
{
    struct a
    {
        struct b* x;
    };
}
```

I defined `struct a` to contain a pointer `x` to `struct b` without defining `struct b`. I was expecting an error. Even by including `-Wall`, I got nothing from the compiler. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: It knows how to make pointers. But you can't dereference it (`*x`) without defining `struct b`.

Comment: In context, `struct b` is an incomplete or opaque type.  They're actually quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just a standard language feature. `struct b` is now an incomplete type. There's not much you can do with incomplete types. But one thing you *can* do is declare pointers to incomplete types.

You will be able to complete that type later by providing a full declaration for `struct b`. After that it will become a normal struct type.

Comment: When I remove the `*`, I got `error: field 'x' has incomplete type`. Does it mean that it is illegal to include an incomplete type but legal to include a pointer to an incomplete type? How can this be useful?

Comment: @W. Zhu: Yes, it is legal to declare pointers to incomplete types, but illegal to declare objects of incomplete types. It is hugely useful for many different purposes, like implementation hiding (opaque types). In fact, it is not possible to declare a simple linked list without relying on this feature. Again, remember that incomplete type becomes complete type later, when (and where) it is fully declared.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an [incomplete type](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Incomplete-Types) and it is perfectly fine to have a pointer of such type, but it can't be instantiated unless you complete it.

> 2.7 Incomplete Types
>
> You can define structures, unions, and enumerations without listing
>   their members (or values, in the case of enumerations). Doing so
>   results in an incomplete type. You can’t declare variables of
>   incomplete types, but you can work with pointers to those types.
>
> ```
> struct point;
> ```
>
> At some time later in your program you will want to complete the type.
>   You do this by defining it as you usually would:
>
> ```
> struct point {
>     int x, y;
> };
> ```
>
> This technique is commonly used to for linked lists:
>
> ```
> struct singly_linked_list   {
>     struct singly_linked_list *next;
>     int x;
>     /* other members here perhaps */
> };
> struct singly_linked_list *list_head;
> ```

Comment: Does it mean `struct a` contains a pointer to an empty struct?

Comment: @W.Zhu. Sorry about the previous answer, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler can allocate the structure since it knows the size of a pointer, but you cannot use `x` because the compiler will not know how to dereference the pointer unless there is a definition for the structure.

You can take advantage of this by using *forward declarations*, you can declare a pointer of an unknown `struct` type and avoid including a possible large header file only for the structure thus improving compilation time and effort.